# Where does phaser reference 'useFrames' of tween?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am using phaser3 with Phaser.Tweens.

But tween have a dependency on device's performance. Preventing it, use 'useFrames'.

for example)

```
var tween = this.tweens.add({
    targets: textObj,
    alpha: 1.0,
    x: 300,
    delay: 0,
    yoyo: true,
    repeat: -1,
    duration: 1000,
    useFrames: true
  });

...
var frameNumber = 0;
function update(time, delta) {
  frameNumber++;
  if (frameNumber == 250) {
    console.log(textObj.x);
  }
}
```

You can refer or modify example: https://codesandbox.io/s/phaser-3-template-5uu48

result is: 254.20000000000002

All devices show 254.20000000000002. If useframes is false, different log will be showed in all devices.

I am watching view phaser3 source in order to understand useFrames.

```
    /**
     * Internal method that advances the Tween based on the time values.
     *
     * @method Phaser.Tweens.Tween#update
     * @fires Phaser.Tweens.Events#TWEEN_COMPLETE
     * @fires Phaser.Tweens.Events#TWEEN_LOOP
     * @fires Phaser.Tweens.Events#TWEEN_START
     * @since 3.0.0

    update: function (timestamp, delta)
    {
        if (this.state === TWEEN_CONST.PAUSED)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (this.useFrames)
        {
            delta = 1 * this.parent.timeScale;
        }

        delta *= this.timeScale;
```

Above code only refer useFrames to use parent.timeScale.

I can't find timestamp of system anywhere.

I hope to understand useFrames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found answer.

```
 @method Phaser.Core.TimeStep#step
```

Above step function makes delta, then its value propagate to tween's delta.

We just assign delta value to ignore its delta.